# Boolean value inconsistent

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am building a website using App Engine and weird thing just happened. There is boolean variable that I used in one of my databases

```
class UserTable(db.Expando):
    isVerified = db.BooleanProperty()
```

in next few lines, I am going to change its value from the default false to true by typing this

```
TheUser = UserTable.get_by_key_name(Theusername)
logging.info(TheUser.isVerified)
TheUser.isVerified = True
logging.info(TheUser.isVerified)
```

Then my log files showed that the value had been changed, but the GUI datastore viewer said the other way, it was still false as if nothing had happened. Any idea why? thank you

Comment: have you commit the changes back to the database ?

Comment: What do you mean? I set the Boolean to be false when initiated the entity that contains it, and did lines above trying to change it to true. Thanks

Comment: Commit means have you save the changes to database?

Comment: I thought I did. Turns out I forgot to call the put(). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the datastore [intro](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview.html#Introducing_the_Python_Datastore) docs.  You need to put the entity to save it after making your changes.

```
theuser = UserTable.get_by_key_name(Theusername)
theuser.isVerified = True
theuser.put()
```

Comment: I totally forgot about that, I thought you only need to put() when you create entities. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is what you want to do when you change any object in memory and want same changes in database.